# UIAlertController disables all Touch events on screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, uialertcontroller

I have to show a view with a picker, cancel and done buttons using UIAlertController. Here is code that I have written:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
        UIAlertAction *alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:alertAction];
        [alertController.view addSubview:pickerView];
        [alertController.view addSubview:cancelBtn];
        [alertController.view addSubview:doneBtn];
        [alertController.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 180, self.view.frame.size.width, 400)];
```

and this is how I call the present view controller method:

```
UIPopoverPresentationController *popover = alertController.popoverPresentationController;
       if (popover)
       {
          popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 550);
          popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
        }
 [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After the alert controller screen is present on screen, I am unable to tap on cancel and done buttons and also anywhere on the screen. Please help me to solve this issue.

Without settings bounds the cancel and done buttons appear at the bottom of the page:
[image]

Whenever I set bounds to alertcontroller, I am able to see a proper view but not able to select anything:
[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I would bet your bounds are not correct. So this line:

> [alertController.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 180, self.view.frame.size.width, 400)];

is setting your view bounds to start at 180.

***EDIT: Based on the comments below*** If you want to set the buttons position you should modify your buttons frame, not the alertview bounds.

Remember the frame is the view position according to the parent view coordinate system. The Bounds are the view limits related to its own coordinate system.

Comment: I have verified it. Bounds width is not 0.

Comment: Add a block on presentViewController completion that prints the view bounds and size. The problem you are having with the click not being detected is usually related with bounds.

Comment: Added. The values that I set was getting printed.

Comment: Why are you starting your bounds at 180? Be aware that the bounds are defined according the own view coordinate system. Sorry to insist, this issue is usually related with bounds.

Comment: Whenever I comment and run the bounds line, I am able to touch on cancel and done buttons. But those are getting appeared at the bottom of the page. Selection to user will be an issue, if that is the case. So I set it is 180.

Comment: You should set the buttons frame to the position you want them to appear. Remember the frame is the view position related to the superview coordinate system. The bounds are the view limits related to its own coordinates system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63764/discussion-between-dee-and-carlescf).

Comment: Please check the images that I have added.